# React.js router going to other page renders blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

First of all, I am using stateless components (functional)
The problem I am running into is this: 
When going to another route via Link component I am getting the blank page, and after refreshing the page the component loads.
I have all my routes inside the App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/panele" component={Dashboard}  />
      <Route path="/prisijungimas" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/skelbimas/:id">
        <HeadLine>
          <h1>
            SURASK DARBĄ <span>GREIČIAU</span> IR <span>EFEKTYVIAU</span>
          </h1>
        </HeadLine>
        <SingleJobPost />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/" component={AllJobPosts} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

);

To be honest I am kinda desperate over here. When I don't have the exact attribute on the route component pages are loading - but it is stacking on each other - this is not ok for me.

EDIT:
The Dashboard component:

```
 const Dashboard = props => {
  let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
  let history = useHistory();
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  let header = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("header");

  return (
    <>
      {data === null ? (
        <>{history.push("/prisijungimas")}</>
      ) : (
        <DashboardWrapper>
          <Navigation>
            <DashboardLogo>
              <img src={dashboardLogo} />
              <h1>Valdymo panelė</h1>
            </DashboardLogo>

            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/panele/skelbimuvaldymas?header=Valdykite sukurtus darbo pasiūlymus">
                    Sukurtų darbo pasiūlymų valdymas
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Pranešimai</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Pagalbos centras</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Vartotoju valdymas</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Logs</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Mano profilis</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </Navigation>

          <EditorWindow>
            <EditorHeader>
              <h1>{header}</h1>
            </EditorHeader>
            <Editor id="style-1">
              <Switch>
                <Route path={`${path}/skelbimas`}>
                  <JobPost />
                </Route>
                <Route
                  path={`${path}/skelbimuvaldymas`}
                  component={ControlJobPost}
                />
              </Switch>
            </Editor>
          </EditorWindow>
        </DashboardWrapper>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Also what particular url is giving you that issue?

Comment: @lomse I have a problem with all the URL's all of them loads the white page, and the errors I get is not related to the roating problem - the error appears when the component doesn't load.

Comment: Could you paste your component code as well.

Comment: As @Sohail pointed out, without the content of the component, it will be difficult to understand your issue

Comment: @Sohail I added the code of the dashboard component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem this way:

It works with the functional component as well - I approached it this way:

First of all, make sure to make an if statement to check it the values are loaded if it is not that render empty block otherwise render the actual component with all the data.

```
 {!posts ? (
        <></>
      ) : ( COMPONENT) }
```

The secound thingy which fixed the problem was - in uedEffect method calling async 
function, not doing all the logic inside the method it self.

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios("http://localhost:1337/jobposts?confirmed=true");
    setPosts(result.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the component stateful and handle the data via state.

```
const Dashboard = props => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  let history = useHistory();
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    let data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
    setData(() => {
      data
    });
  }, []);

  let header = new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get("header");

  return (
    <>
      {data === null ? (
        <>{history.push("/prisijungimas")}</>
      ) : (
        <DashboardWrapper>
          <Navigation>
            <DashboardLogo>
              <img src={dashboardLogo} />
              <h1>Valdymo panelė</h1>
            </DashboardLogo>

            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/panele/skelbimuvaldymas?header=Valdykite sukurtus darbo pasiūlymus">
                    Sukurtų darbo pasiūlymų valdymas
                  </Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Pranešimai</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Pagalbos centras</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Vartotoju valdymas</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Logs</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <Link path="/panele/valdymas">Mano profilis</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </Navigation>

          <EditorWindow>
            <EditorHeader>
              <h1>{header}</h1>
            </EditorHeader>
            <Editor id="style-1">
              <Switch>
                <Route path={`${path}/skelbimas`}>
                  <JobPost />
                </Route>
                <Route
                  path={`${path}/skelbimuvaldymas`}
                  component={ControlJobPost}
                />
              </Switch>
            </Editor>
          </EditorWindow>
        </DashboardWrapper>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: That is not the way to go, I already tried it, it was the same issue :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. The only potential issue is with the data, react performs action async, it is possible that react will render the component before the data is ready. So making it stateful should do the trick.

Comment: Nope, it does not work, I already tried it, I also deleted the HTTP request and getting the same result, white blank page, until the page is being reloaded

Comment: Could you console the data and see if it is printed in console on first load?

Comment: I found the fix I posted it as an answer, but anyways thank you! :)